# Java - Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to void

Tags: java, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

I'm using java and this seems like a very straightforward ternary condition.

```
String severity = obj.getJsonObject("impact").isEmpty() ? "N/A" : obj.getJsonObject("impact").getJsonObject("baseMetricV2").getString("severity");
```

This is the error it throws me on this:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to void
```

I have come from C# background so maybe I'm missing something very obvious.

Comment: Are you trying to return that? (from a function that returns void)

Comment: @XtremeBaumer That's just a copy paste thing here. Editted it.

Comment: Is this compile issue or runtime issue? When does the error show itself?

Comment: @EvdzhanMustafa It's runtime.

Comment: What version of Java are you using? Are those methods form [this json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json) library?

Comment: Can you show us the full stack trace attached to the error message?

Comment: @JettoMartínez They are from `io.vertx.core.json.JsonArray`. Java 17.

Comment: `JsonArray.getJsonObject` takes an `int` argument, but you're passing a `String` instead. Are you sure the error message isn't "cannot convert from String to **int**"?

Comment: @k314159 This function takes string in order to return the object for that string key value. `JsonObject io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject.getJsonObject(String key)`

Comment: You are probably returning a string from a method with a void return type.

Comment: But you said this is a runtime error, not a compile-time one? Can you just reconfirm? If it really is a runtime error, is there a stack trace you can show?

Answer (score 0):

From the code and error that has been provided it is not clear that what could cause the error!

```
obj.getJsonObject("impact").getJsonObject("baseMetricV2").getString("severity");
```

But looking at what has been provided, the `.getString("severity")` is probably returning void , that means the return type of getString() is void;

Check return type of getString() method!